# LOVE2D error can't run my game after .love

Tags: lua, love2d

trying to export my game to .love but every time i try to run it i get this error:

```
Error

boot.lua:577: Cannot load game at path 'C:/Users/<myusername>/Desktop/snook/snook.love'.
Make sure a folder exists at the specified path.


Traceback

[C]: in function 'error'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: well does that file exist? share how you came to this error.

Comment: Does `<myusername>` contain non-English letters?

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful:

http://love2d.org/wiki/Game_Distribution

> To create a .love-file you have to create a zip file of the whole game directory. Make sure that your main.lua is in the root of the archive.

Rather than using your compressing utility to zip up the folder containing the files, select them, then compress them. Rename the .zip to .love, and it should work.

If that doesn't work, make sure your paths are correct (as mentioned above).